# How to disable remote ssh and local download in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How to disable remote ssh and local download in Visual Studio code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.